# Kafka Streams - Transformers with State in Fields and Task / Threading Model

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Transformer with a state store that uses punctuate to operate on said state store.
After a few iterations of punctuate, the operation may have finished, so I'd like to cancel the punctuate -- but only for the Task that has actually finished the operation on the partition's respective state store. The punctuate operations for the Tasks that are not done yet should keep running. To that purpose my transformer keeps a reference to the Cancellable returned by schedule().

As far as I can tell, every Task always gets its own isolated Transformer instance and every Task gets its own isolated scheduled punctuate() within that instance (?)

However, since this is effectively state, but not inside a stateStore, I'm not sure how safe this is. For instance, are there certain scenarios in which one transformer instance might be shared across tasks (and therefore absolutely no state must be kept outside of StateStores)?

```
public class CoolTransformer implements Transformer {

  private KeyValueStore stateStore;
  private Cancellable taskPunctuate; // <----- Will this lead to conflicts between tasks?


  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.store =  context.getStateStore(...);
    this.taskPunctuate = context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(...), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, this::scheduledOperation);
    
  }

  private void scheduledOperation(long l) {
    stateStore.get(...)
    // do stuff...

    if (done) {
      this.taskPunctuate.cancel(); // <----- Will this lead to conflicts between tasks?
    }
  }

  public KeyValue transform(key, value) {
    // do stuff
    stateStore.put(key, value)  
  }

  public void close() {
    taskPunctuate.cancel();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to look into [TransformerSupplier](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TransformerSupplier.html), specifically `TransformSupplier#get()`, this will ensure that ensure we new transformer will be created for when they should be kept independent. Also the Transformers should not share objects, so be careful of this with your `Cancellable taskPunctuate`. If either of these cases are violated you should see errors like `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Current node is unknown`, `ConcurrentModificationException` or `InstanceAlreadyExistsException`.